# How to find folder size in Perl using File::stat module?

Tags: linux, perl

Below is the Perl script to find the file size using [`File::stat`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::stat) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

my $directory = "/home/dinkar/index.html";

my $dirStats  = stat($directory);
my $size      = $dirStats->size;

printf("Size of %s: %d", $directory, $size);
printf("\n");
```

I get the right output for file size but this code doesn't work for finding the folder size. It just takes the count of the files inside the folder. For example, if there are eight files inside the folder `/home/dinkar`, I get the output for the folder as 8 which is wrong.

I want to find the folder size in Perl using `File::stat module`. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`File::stat`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::stat) module is nothing but a more accessible interface to the built-in `stat` operator. Since `stat` does not offer a way of retrieving the "size" of a directory, nor does `File::stat`.

What you mean by a directory's size is the sum of the sizes of all files that it contains, or are in directories recursively beneath it. You have to calculate that manually, and the best tool is probably [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find).

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use File::Find;

my $total;

find(sub { $total += -s if -f }, '/home/dinkar');

say $total;
```

If there are many files to be measured then this may take several seconds to complete.

Comment: Cant we find using File::stat module instead of File::Find module?

Comment: No. I explained why. Why are you so eager to use `File::stat` when it is the wrong choice of module? Is this homework?

Comment: No Thanks. I just clarified. Sorry I didnt see your explanation

Comment: -f is file and -d is directory. So your program demonstrates to find the file size and not folder size?

Comment: As I said, what mean by "folder size" is usually the sum of the sizes of the files it contains. If you mean the space occupied by the directory node itself then I can't help you.

Comment: Yes.you are right...I meant "folder size" as the sum of the sizes of the files it contains.

Answer (score -1):

This is a linux, not a Perl question: A folder in linux is just a file that contains names of file, therefore the size is just the size of those names, as you noticed.

http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html

> A Linux system, just like UNIX, makes no difference between a file and a directory, since a directory is just a file containing names of other files

If you want the size of all files in the directory, you will have to sum them up yourself by reading all files <del>with readdir</del> and summing up the sizes found <del>with File::stat</del>.

Comment: The OP has asked how to find the total size of a directory *using Perl*. I don't see how that is a Linux question. And the module they are using is `File::stat`, not `File::Stat`. Unfortunately they are two different modules (which means that you can't have both installed on Windows at the same time).

Comment: Corrected the typo. Okay, the misconception about Linux directories was just one problem.